# elementary OS Juno installer crashed

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

When trying to install the elementary OS 5.0 on system fails - the installer crashed even before starting to copy files. The bootable usb was created with

```
dd if=</path/to/eOS.iso> of=</path/to/device>
```

System booted in UEFI + Secure Boot enabled. But with same iso i can install on VirtualBox VM.

screenshot -[image: IO/Error]
installer - crashed screen

[image: installer-crashed screenshot]

As indicated it seems like IO error for the bootable device. So tried check media for defects - The option doesn't perform any checks and system restarts again.

Then tried with another usb bootable - the same issue. The logs from /var/log/installer/dm

```
(nm-applet:1263): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:23:29.696: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(nm-applet:1263): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:23:29.704: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
ubiquity-dm: greeter exited with code 1
ubiquity-dm: Failed with an exception:
ubiquity-dm: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubiquity-dm", line 885, in main
    ret = run(vt, display, username)
  File "/usr/bin/ubiquity-dm", line 860, in run
    ret = dm.run(*sys.argv[4:])
  File "/usr/bin/ubiquity-dm", line 749, in run
    db = DebconfCommunicator('ubiquity', cloexec=True)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/debconfcommunicator.py", line 37, in __init__
    write=self.dccomm.stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.setUp(title)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py", line 74, in setUp
    self.version = self.version(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    lambda *args, **kw: self.command(command, *args, **kw))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py", line 104, in command
    status = int(status)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Gdk-Message: 20:56:26.952: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 20:56:26.953: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 20:56:26.953: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 20:56:26.953: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 20:56:26.954: gala: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Gdk-Message: 20:56:26.954: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 461 requests (461 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
dbus-daemon[1262]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.8' (uid=999 pid=20661 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-acceler" label="unconfined")
dbus-daemon[1262]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
```

There are so many messages in debug log to show here here are some that I get repetitively -

```
(ubiquity:1270): IBUS-WARNING **: 15:15:19.994: The owner of /home/elementary/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:5: PyGIWarning: NM was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('NM', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
...
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-console-setup.py:74: Warning: Source ID 2019 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.keyboard_variant_timeout_id)
...
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/segmented_bar.py:34: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, PangoCairo

(ubiquity:1270): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:18:11.401: gtk_widget_set_allocation: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_visible (widget) || _gtk_widget_is_toplevel (widget)' failed
...
(ubiquity:1270): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:19:59.249: gtk_widget_set_allocation: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_visible (widget) || _gtk_widget_is_toplevel (widget)' failed
...
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session”
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:98: PyGIWarning: Soup was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Soup', '2.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib, Soup
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:209: Warning: Source ID 14696 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:209: Warning: Source ID 14752 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-timezone.py:209: Warning: Source ID 14810 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
Ecryptfs is deprecated
Ecryptfs is deprecated
/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-usersetup.py:394: Warning: Source ID 15095 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.hostname_timeout_id)
...
Gtk-Message: 20:56:22.084: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
No such schema “com.canonical.indicator.session”
```

Can someone help in understanding why it failed?

Answer (score 1):

### First

You used:

```
dd if=</path/to/eOS.iso> of=</path/to/device>
```

Please use in the future:

```
dd bs=4M if=</path/to/eOS.iso of=</path/to/device> status=progress oflag=sync
```

or

```
dd bs=4M if=</path/to/eOS.iso of=</path/to/device> status=progress && sync
```

---

### About the Question

Looks like your hard drive just died or if you are lucky is just an error that can be repaired...

---

> I'll use `/dev/sda` but your disk can be different, check with `sudo fdisk -l` if you don't know

Check with:

- `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

  - Probably here you'll get the error: `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error`
- `sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda` *(optional, to get more info)*

> *If you don't have the `smartctl` command and you want to install it, use `sudo apt-get install smartmontools`*

---

Try to repair the disk with:

- `sudo fsck /dev/sda`

---

If you need to repair a partition of /dev/sda use (X is the partition number):

- `sudo fsck /dev/sdaX`

Answer (score 0):

DD makes bad stick. You can use special apps better. I made flash drive with rufus on win7 (my second system in dualboot). It was easier and better way for me. You can boot liveCD and write flash drive with unetbootin or etcher

Comment: I don't have any windows machine. Any alternative for linux/BSD? I just know unetbootin and dd. tried both